# How to use GPU to do coordinate-transformation of Point Cloud?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, ros, point-cloud-library

The tf-transform is really very slow under CPU. I'm thinking about how to transform coordinate of point cloud using GPU. This process can be done only with a matrix multiplication.

However, how to use add .cu file in ROS package and how to call function in .cu file?

Anyone has done this or is there any example about this?
It seems there is no API in PCL.

Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

you can add .cu files into ROS build space like other projects. Remember it's just CMake projects with additional libraries.

for calling function to .cu i can refer you to [How to CUDA C](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp) And [Even Easier Introduction to CUDA](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/).

**EDIT 1**

CUDA Matrix multiplication for CUDA 9.2 in Their [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples)

Comment: Should also be some example matrix multiplications samples for visual studio included with the NVidia Cuda SDK.